# React / How to pass the condition when checkbox is checked

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I'm making ToDo List app in React.

In Form component, I put a checkbox. If checkbox is checked and form was submitted, I want to display the word "Important" on Item component.

Right now, when checked it updates state in App component. But how do I let Item component know that the checkbox has been checked?

```
class App extends React.Component {

   state = { defaultList: todo, checked: false }

    onSubmit = (task) => {        
        this.state.defaultList.push({task});
        this.setState(todo);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form 
                    onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}
                    checkCheckBox = {this.handleCheckBox}
                />
                <List 
                    lists = {this.state.defaultList}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
class Form extends React.Component {

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.onSubmit(this.refs.userInput.value);
        this.refs.userInput.value = "";
    }

    handleCheckClick = () => {
        this.props.setState({ checked: !this.props.state.checked });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>Task</label>
                        <input ref="userInput" />
                        <p className="warning"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input 
                        type="checkbox" 
                        checkCheckBox={this.handleCheckClick} 
                        onChange={this.handleCheckClick} 
                        />
                        <label>Important</label>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit">ADD</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
const Item = ({task, priority, checkChecked}) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li><b>{task}</b></li>
            <li>
            {checkChecked && <span>{priority}</span>} // Write a if statement here
            </li>
            <li>Delete</li>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some comment and edit to your code. In general:
use state to track the state of you componente
don't call setstate on props
if you need to call a parent function, you must call in as: this.props.functionName

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state =  { defaultList: todo, checked: false }
    }


     onSubmit = (task) => {      
         //create a copy of state
         let newState ={ ...this.state.defaultList}
         newState.defaultList.push({task});
         this.setState(newState);
     }

     handleCheckBox = (checked) => {
        if(checked){
          //shou your message}
        else{//hide it}
     }

     render() {
         return (
             <div>
                 <Form 
                     onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}
                     checkCheckBox = {this.handleCheckBox}
                 />
                 <List 
                     lists = {this.state.defaultList}
                 />
             </div>
         );
     }
 }


 class Form extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state =  { checkBoxChecked: false }
    }

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.onSubmit(this.refs.userInput.value);
        this.refs.userInput.value = "";
    }

    handleCheckClick = () => {
        //you can't setState on props
        //this.props.setState({ checked: !this.props.state.checked });
        this.setState({checkBoxChecked: !this.state.checkBoxChecked})
        //now if you want do stuff on parent you can call the parent function
        this.props.handleCheckClick(this.state.checkBoxChecked)

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>Task</label>
                        <input ref="userInput" />
                        <p className="warning"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input 
                        type="checkbox" 
                        checked = {this.state.checkBoxChecked}
                        //duplicated handler
                        //checkCheckBox={this.handleCheckClick} 
                        onChange={this.handleCheckClick} 
                        />
                        <label>Important</label>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit">ADD</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I can't setState parent's state from child. I'm still trying to figure out how I can add a comment "important" when I check the checkbox...

Comment: i've edited my example, let me know if you've understood

Comment: Thank you, it worked. It changes the state of App component. I'm trying to display the "Important" message on Item component, and it seems that only App component can communicate with Item component. There might be a way to let Item component to know that the checkbox was checked, but so far I can't figure out how to do that..

Comment: you need to keep passing the function to nested components to let every compomponent know it, or you can use redux( in this case there will be a global state that every component can read and every time it change everyone will now it)

Comment: I haven’t learnt Redux unfortunately :( Still can’t find how to display a message when checkbook is checked since the state changes only on App component. I understand I have to pass through function, and that’s the thing I want to know how to do...

Comment: @kayak inside handleCheckClick, as you can see in my answer, we call the this.props.handleCheckClick(this.state.checkBoxChecked) .This is the function passed to the form component , and we are passing to it the checkbox state, so inside the app componente the function handler handleCheckBox will receive in the param true or false. If true you can show stuff inside your render function just setting a state variable to true and hide it setting the state to false. let me know if you got it

Comment: I think I should change my question, now I need to find how to add a new value to existing object. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @kayak i need some code to understand better, try to add a new question with code and link me the url

Comment: Umm, whats the package you import?